# Programmatically Controlling Playback in FCP

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsnotifications, finalcut

I ran the Unix "strings" command on the Final Cut Pro binary and it returns some stuff like this:

```
nextEdit:
previousEdit:
stepForward:
stepBackward:
playPause:
```

Is there any way that I can tell Final Cut to run these functions while it's running?  Could this possibly have to do with NSNotifications?  I can't find any Apple Documentation on it.

If I'm going about this the wrong way, is there any way I can programmatically control playback (play/pause/rewind/etc.) in Final Cut?

Comment: IF there is a mechanism, it is probably through Apple Script.

Comment: AppleScript is okay too.  There's no public info from Apple, and if you try to open the FCPX AppleScript dictionary with AppleScript editor, nothing happens.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6430030

The arguably lame approach is to send keyboard short cuts. Works for me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While we appreciate your willingness to help, your answer is not really complete, I think it is comment worthy. It is in danger of [link rot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) as well. Please improve your answer by at least quoting relevant information from the linked website.